# ubunu 10.10 unable to upgrade to any latest version

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Since Ubuntu 10.10 is now sent to stone age , i tried upgrading it to 11.04 but

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

gives

```
   Hash Sum mismatch 
, E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
=== Command detached from window (Wed May 22 10:37:21 2013) ===
Press x to destroy or r to resurrect window  d May 22 10:37:21 2013) ===
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documented process yet for upgrading from 10.10 now that it is unsupported, but there is documentation on upgrading from some of the earlier unsupported versions that may be helpful to you.  You may be able to adapt the information to your situation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Jaunty

You can still find the Natty sources online:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: That kinda made it much easier solves 70% of he problems.... but still i guess fresh installation will be required anyhow